# Print only fields of matched header starting after matched records

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep, cut

I'm trying to extract specific fields from my file. Basically, output fields only containing a matched expression, with output starting after the matched records.

This is an example of my input. Sometimes the fields are in different orders as well as having a different number of lines before the header I'm trying to match.

I was having a hard time finding out how to achieve this with cut and sed commands and couldn't quite find an awk method.

```
CGATS.17
FORMAT_VERSION  1
KEYWORD "SampleID"
KEYWORD "SAMPLE_NAME"
NUMBER_OF_FIELDS    45
WEIGHTING_FUNCTION "ILLUMINANT, D50"
WEIGHTING_FUNCTION "OBSERVER, 2 degree"
BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT
SampleID    SAMPLE_NAME CMYK_C  CMYK_M  CMYK_Y  CMYK_K  LAB_L   LAB_A   LAB_B   nm380   nm390   nm400
END_DATA_FORMAT
NUMBER_OF_SETS  182
BEGIN_DATA
1   1   40  40  40  0   62.5    6.98    4.09    0.195213    0.205916    0.212827
2   2   0   40  40  0   73.69   25.48   24.89   0.200109    0.211081    0.218222
3   3   40  40  0   0   63.95   12.14   -20.91  0.346069    0.365042    0.377148
4   4   0   70  70  0   58.91   47.69   35.54   0.080033    0.084421    0.087317
END_DATA
```

This is the dirty code I used which mostly did the job but without the field header conditional search. The awk command is just to remove empty lines surrounding the output.

```
cut -f 7-9 -s input.txt | 
sed -E 's/(LAB_.)//g' |
awk 'NF' > file.txt
```

The output I would expect appears like this. It's still tab-delimited containing only the values of the fields starting directly under (LAB_.)

```
62.5    6.98    4.09
73.69   25.48   24.89
63.95   12.14   -20.91
58.91   47.69   35.54
```

Comment: +1, a perfectly organized and formatted question! Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# We look for line starting with BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT do the getline function and 
# store location of fields that have "LAB" in their name on the next line.

/^BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT/{
        getline
            for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                    if ($i~/LAB/) a[i]=$i
                } 

# In this regex range we look for lines that have more than 2 fields. For those 
# lines we loop thru each field and see if the location matches to the ones 
# captured in our earlier array (i.e location number of fields that have "LAB" 
# in their name). If we find a match we print those fields. 

/^BEGIN_DATA$/,/^END_DATA$/{
             s="";
             if (NF<2) next; else 
                for (j in a)
            s=s?s"\t"$j:$j
            print s; 
                 }
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] ./script.awk file
62.5    6.98    4.09    
73.69   25.48   24.89   
63.95   12.14   -20.91  
58.91   47.69   35.54
```

Comment: thanks for the instantaneous response! It works on the input data with shortened fields that I posted but it wasn't working on the large file I had. I figured out that it's because my line endings are CRLF. It does work on LF though! The results also have the tab-spacing removed along with one empty line at the top and two lines with space characters at the bottom.

Comment: You can modify it as per your file. In the for loop play around with values. Note the column you want to start capturing from and the last column you want. Then you can put those values in the for loop.

Comment: You can use dos2unix utility to remove the CRLF. For empty lines i can give you an updated answer in a few hrs. Dont have a shell handy!

Comment: For empty lines try this `/^BEGIN_DATA$/,/^END_DATA$/ && NF {for...` if it doesnt work then ill get you a working solution once im home.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I'm not sure if I'm describing it in the best way but I'm trying to find a technique where I don't have to set the actual number of the field. My experience on the syntax in your loop is brand new so maybe you're saying I can play around with it by matching (LAB_.)

Comment: @JaypalSingh nice solution. the 2nd part (nesting loop) may have room to optimize.. e.g. with single loop. since the outter loop does actually nothing.

Comment: Thanks so much @Kent. I have made the changes as per your suggestions and you are right, using `getline` function is much better for capturing location.

Comment: Thanks, this new version successfully gives the output I was looking for. I was wondering about how to modify the printf portion to make it so there is no tab after the last field of values. Would a conditional  statement be a good way to do this?

Comment: @JeffBauer You're welcome. Yes, `conditional statements` would be a good way to go about it. However, in cases like these `ternary operators` come in handy. They are short and do exactly the same. I have modified the solution to use the `ternary operator` as Kent has shown. This will remove the extra `tab` after last set of values.

Comment: Thanks it works like a dream. I was trying to figure out the s in the ternary operator that Kent wrote but I was thinking it looked like the operator I wanted. Now I just need to become more familiar with variables in awk. Thanks again.

Comment: @JeffBauer Awesome!! You're most welcome. I am glad I could be of help. :)

Answer (score 1):

another awk script:

```
 awk '/^BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT/{getline;f=NF;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^LAB_[LAB]/)l[i]++;} 
/^BEGIN_DATA/,/^END_DATA/ && NF==f{s=""; for(x in l)s=s?s"\t"$x:$x; print s;}' input
```

the output of your example input:

```
62.5    6.98    4.09
73.69   25.48   24.89
63.95   12.14   -20.91
58.91   47.69   35.54
```

some notes on the awk script above:

- The header handling is similar as @JayPal's solution, but with slight
  different: you mentioned that the column order could be different, so
  for the header matching, my awk script looked up the next line of
  "BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT". since the 1st column of head line could
  something other than SampleID.
- in the output, as you expected, print only values ([tab] separated),
  but no header. if you said the order of column could be variable, you
  may lose the header info. say, which column is LAB_L which is A? etc.
  this could be easily done if it is really needed.

Comment: Thanks again @Kent for your feedback. +1 to this answer.

Comment: QQ @Kent: Can you please explain me the portion where you have used ternary operator `s=s?s"\t"$x:$x; print s;`? It is much better than the one I have used in my solution using `printf` and then `print ""` to get newline.

Comment: @JaypalSingh it will construct the string (s) first, and then print it out, with '\n' by print statement. s=s?s"\t"$x:$x means, if s is not empty, concatenates a '\t' between values ($x); if s is empty, the $x would be the first value, therefore we don't need the leading '\t'. the initial value of s is empty (""). so the first testing s? would be false.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/^BEGIN_DATA\>/,/^END_DATA\>/{//d;s/\(\S*\s*\)\{6\}\(\S*\s*\S*\s*\S*\).*/\2/p};d' file
```

Or staying with `cut`:

```
cut -f7-9 file | sed '/^\([-.0-9]*\s*[-.0-9]*\s*[-.0-9.]*$\)/!d'
```

Or (but I'm guessing here at the format of you input file):

```
sed 's/\s*$//' file | cut -f7-9 | sed '/^BEGIN_DATA$/,/^END_DATA$/{//d;p};d'
```